# How does the message notifications disappears from the notification tray?

Tags: ios, silentpush

> I have checked the scenario where i got the text messages notifications
>   on my iPhone device, i read those message from my mac iMessage application then
>   the notification which is there on the device notification tray are
>   automatically disappeared.
>
> **How does it work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook does that also.

Possibly it's done with a silent push notification that lets the app know that a specific message has been read?

Comment: yeah, so it is handled from server side?

Comment: Yes, there probably is a last_message_read with a specific id, and when this is updated (either from the Mac App, or the iOS app), a silent notification is sent to update the other apps with that information.